# Not equal condition with findAll()

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I am trying to pull record from a table using the following code

```
$userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
$lists = PromoLists::findAll(['user_id' => $userId, 'list_type' => 'custom']);
```

which outputs a query like below

```
select * from promo_lists where user_id ='$userId' and list_type='custom'
```

But i am unable to find any thing in the documentation that would help me achieve it with the following condition.

```
select * from promo_lists where user_id ='$userId' and list_type='custom' and status!='deleted'
```

as the status is an `ENUM` field and there are 4 different status

```
'active','pending','rejected','deleted'
```

currently i used the following approach

```
PromoLists::findAll(['user_id' => $userId, 'list_type' => 'custom', 'status'=>['active','pending','rejected']]);
```

which outputsthe following query

```
select * from promo_lists where user_id ='$userId' and list_type='custom' and status in ('active','pending','rejected')
```

which somehow achieves the same thing but this query would need to be edited every time when there is a new status type added to the table column `status`.

i know  i can do this by using `PromoLists::find()->where()->andWhere()->all()`

but how to check with `!=` / `<>` operator using `findAll()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
PromoLists::find()->where(['and',
    [
        'user_id' => $userId, 
        'list_type' => 'custom',
    ],
    ['<>', 'status', 'deleted'],
])->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using operator format in condition

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#operator-format

```
PromoLists::find()
    ->andWhere([
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'list_type' => 'custom',
        ['!=', 'status', 'deleted']
    ])
    ->all();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.